# Python CNTK, why does the minibatch data not batched?

Tags: cntk

I'm training a model using the language understanding model in CNTK examples.
It's a sequence tagging problem. For each word in each query, you want to predict the correct label (out of 16 possible labels).

Here's what I did

```
        minibatch_size = 5
    data = reader.next_minibatch(minibatch_size, input_map={  # fetch minibatch
        x: reader.streams.query,
        y: reader.streams.slot_labels
    })
    if not data:                                 # until we hit the end
        break

    evaluator = C.eval.Evaluator(loss, progress_printer)
    evaluator.test_minibatch(data)
    res = model.eval(data)
    print("data[y].shape=", data[y].shape)
    print("")
    print("len(res)=", len(res), " shape=", res[0].shape)
```

THe shape of data[y].shape is 1 * 3 * 16, or 2 * 4 * 16 etc.

I figured 3/4 means the number of words in my query. 16 is the size of the one-hot vector. So 1/ has to be the batch size. However, I set the batch size to be 5, why is it not equal to 5?

Another confusing thing is that, if I do "t += data[y].num_samples", t can be ~60 in the beginning. What does num_samples and num_sequences mean in minibatchData?

Moreover, if it's 2 * 4 * 16, does it mean two queries all have length 4? Does it imply that the program will shuffle my test data to combine queries of the same length? Or in general, if I set randomized=False, should the order be the same as my test data?

Comment: Follow-up: Actually. it's not always 1 * 3 * 16. Sometimes it's   2 * 3 * 16 etc. But why is it not 5?

Answer (score 0):

Because CNTK counts each data point of a sequence as a "sample" and the minibatch size is specified in samples not the number of sequences.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/interpreting-epoch_size-and-minibatch_size_in_samples-and-minibatchsource.next_minibatch-in-cntk